# Safari - keep passwords pref unlocked for longer

Tags: macos, safari, password

I have some 'legacy' passwords that are duplicated or no longer secure, so I'm trying to go down the list in Safari prefs to check & change them, or close old unused accounts on sites I haven't looked at in a decade.

The main issue is that the passwords list re-locks after about 30 seconds, so I constantly unlocking it to see the info.
It does this *even as I'm interacting with the window.*

I'm discovering that as I'm working with it, it will actually relock 2 or 3 times in a row, even whilst I'm actually typing new information in. I unlock… it locks again.
As you can imagine, this is pretty irritating, & I'm still only on the A's…

[image]

Is there any method to extend this 'unlock' period?

Comment: It's not 30s anymore is it?